# Easier way to transform FormData into query string

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I’m sending a POST request via `XMLHttpRequest` with data entered into an HTML form. The form without interference of JavaScript would submit its data encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

With the XMLHttpRequest, I wanted to send the data with via the `FormData` API which does not work since it treats the data as if it were encoded as `multipart/form-data`. Therefor I need to write the data as a query string, properly escaped, into the send method of the `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
addEntryForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    // Gather form data
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    // Array to store the stringified and encoded key-value-pairs.
    var parameters = []
    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        parameters.push(
            encodeURIComponent(pair[0]) + '=' +
            encodeURIComponent(pair[1])
        );
    }

    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open(form.method, form.action);

    httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                console.log('Successfully submitted the request');
            } else {
                console.log('Error while submitting the request');
            }
        }
    };

    httpRequest.send(parameters.join('&'));

    // Prevent submitting the form via regular request
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Now this whole thing with the `for ... of` loop, etc. seems a bit convoluted. Is there a simpler way to transform `FormData` into a query string? Or can I somehow send FormData with a different encoding?

Comment: @Andreas This is one way to make the code shorter, so feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You could use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```
const queryString = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(myForm)).toString()
```

Comment: Great idea, except for current browser support. https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams

Comment: Why do you need `.toString()`?

Comment: @o-t-w because `new URLSeachParams()` returns an object so you need to convert it to a string in order to use it ;)

Comment: @o-t-w, if you don't want to use `.toString()`, try `const queryString = \`new URLSearchParams(new FormData(myForm))\`;`

Comment: In case for someone like me found error in Edge, use Lodash and update the code to this can help. `new URLSearchParams(_.toArray(new FormData(myForm))).toString()`.

Poor MS Edge!

Comment: Issue when checkboxs with same name

Comment: is it possible to get the url path for which you will submit to from FormData?

Comment: @mike01010 the URL isn't usually contained inside the FormData. If your app does, you simply query the value by it's key: `myFormData.get(myKey)`

Comment: @NathanStrutz sorry to follow up on such an old comment - but caniuse says that every browser had support for it in 2018. why did you say that? because edge only got it in a later release?

Comment: @KTibow Internet Explorer, for one (which I was forced to support until like 2021). Looks like it wasn't supported by Edge either until later in 2018. Honestly hard to say really since that was so long ago. All good now, probably a good solution.

Comment: This gives error in Typescript: `Argument of type 'FormData' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Record<string, string> | URLSearchParams | string[][] | undefined'.`

Answer (score 10):

You've asked for a simpler solution...
A `for` loop is the simplest way to traverse over a collection - imho.

But there is a shorter version if you use the [spread operator/syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

> The spread syntax allows an expression to be expanded in places where
>   multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for
>   array literals) or multiple variables  (for destructuring assignment)
>   are expected.

Your `for...of` loop can then be replaced with:

```
let parameters = [...formData.entries()] // expand the elements from the .entries() iterator into an actual array
                     .map(e => encodeURIComponent(e[0]) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(e[1]))  // transform the elements into encoded key-value-pairs
```

Comment: Though I accepted this answer, I do think it's better to write a loop like I did in my question, because it's easier to read.

Answer (score 5):

If you could use `JQuery`, you'll simply call `.serialize()` function on your `form` object, like follow:

```js
function getQueryString() {
  var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
  console.log(str);
}

$( "#cmdTest" ).on( "click", getQueryString );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select name="list1">
    <option>opt1</option>
    <option>opt2</option>
  </select>
 
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="txt1" value="valWith%Special&Char$">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" id="ch1">
  <label for="ch1">check1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" checked="checked" id="ch2">
  <label for="ch2">check2</label>
 
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1" checked="checked" id="r1">
  <label for="r1">radio1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" id="r2">
  <label for="r2">radio2</label>
</form>
  
<button id="cmdTest">Get queryString</button>
```

Note: It also encode data for use it in url request

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: JQuery eventually does something similar. I’m after the algorithmic implementation, not a way to hide the complexity.