# How do i connect my front end to the back end with node js

Tags: html, mysql, rest, sequelize.js

Here is my controller

```
const memberModel =require('../models/index').member
const Op = require('sequelize').Op

exports.getAllMember = async (request, response) => {
    let members = await memberModel.findAll()
    return response.json({
        success:true,
        data:members,
        message: 'member ke load'
    })
}

exports.addMember = (request,response) => {
    let newMember = {
        name: request.body.name,
        address: request.body.address,
        gender: request.body.gender,
        contact: request.body.contact
    }

    memberModel.create(newMember)
    .then(result => {
        return response.json({
            success: true,
            data:result,
            message: 'new membruh'
        })
    })
    .catch(error => {
        return response.json({
            success: false,
            message: error.message
        })
    })
}
```

My routes

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
const memberController = require('../controllers/member.controller')
let { validateMember } = require(`../middlewares/member-validation`)
app.get("/", memberController.getAllMember)
app.post("/", [validateMember], memberController.addMember)
module.exports = app
```

my middleware

```
const Joi = require(`joi`)
const validateMember = (request, response, next) => {
    const rules = Joi
    .object()
    .keys({
        name: Joi.string().required(),
        address: Joi.string().required(),
        contact: Joi.number().required(),
        gender: Joi.string().valid(`Male`, `Female`)

    })
    .options({ abortEarly: false})
    let { error } = rules.validate(request.body)
    if (error != null){
        let errMessage = error.details.map( it => it.message).join(",")
        return response.status(422).json({
            success: false,
            message: errMessage
        })
    }
    next()
}
module.exports = {validateMember}
```

and my main file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 8000; // Use uppercase for constant variable
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // Import body-parser

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Use body-parser to parse form data
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(cors()); // Use app.use() for middleware

const memberRoute = require('./routes/member.route')
app.use('/member', memberRoute)

app.listen(PORT,() => {
    console.log('lezgo 8000')
} )
```

i tried making a simple html form but it doesn't read the form properly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Member</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add Member</h1>

    <form id="memberForm" name="memberForm">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br>

         <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
        <select id="gender" name="gender" required>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select><br>

        <label for="address">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="address" name="address" required><br>

        <label for="contact">Contact:</label>
        <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" required><br>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <div id="message"></div>

    <script>
        const memberForm = document.getElementById('memberForm');
        const message = document.getElementById('message');

        memberForm.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            const formData = new FormData(memberForm);

            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/member', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData,
                });

                const data = await response.json();

                if (data.success) {
                    message.innerHTML = data.message;
                    memberForm.reset();
                } else {
                    message.innerHTML = data.message;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                message.innerHTML = error.message;
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

all these code are working properly, though it displays message from my middleware pointing that my front end is not sending the form data properly("name" is required,"address" is required,"contact" is required)

Answer (score 0):

You need body parsing middleware which supports the data format you are POSTing to the server.

Here you have middleware which supports `application/json` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` bodies:

> ```
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Use body-parser to parse form data
> app.use(bodyParser.json());
> ```

Here you construct a request body encoded as `multipart/form-data`:

> ```
> const formData = new FormData(memberForm);
> ```

The [documentation for body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) (which you are using) links to four middleware modules that do support `multipart/form-data`.

You could also [encode the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48950600/19068) so long as you don't add any file inputs to your form.